# Error in displaying the table after the use of while loop

Tags: javascript, loops, while-loop

As you see my code, I am entering a number in while loop after 2-3 times, but It didn't return any value or table.

I am supposed to display the entered number table. When I enter a number in first attempt, it returns the table but in 3-4 attempt, it only accept the value but not return any table.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var num = prompt('Enter a number for which you want to display the table');
    if(num.length === 0){
        while(num.length === 0){
            var num = prompt('Enter a number for which you want to display the table');
        }
    }else{
        num2 = Number(num);
        for(var i = 1; i <= 10; i++){
            document.write(num2 * i + '<br>');
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need `if` statement and you need to parse `num` as `number`

This should work:

```js
let num = 0;

while (num === 0) {
  num = +prompt('Enter a number for which you want to display the table');
}

num2 = Number(num);
for (var i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
  document.write(num2 * i + '<br>');
}
```